# I am using Geocoder and it does not give location names for few addresses

Tags: android, google-maps

Using Geo coder in Android looking for address based on location name given. I don't find address for some given location names. Below is the code I am using:

```
addressList = geocoder.getFromLocationName(location, 5);
Address address =(Address) addressList.get(0);

                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder();
                sb.append(address.getLatitude()).append("\n");
                sb1.append(address.getLongitude()).append("\n");
                lat = sb.toString();
                lon = sb1.toString();
```

Please can some one tell me why it works for only few addresses?

Comment: Please clarify what the problem is. Are you getting a crash? A null value? Some other data that is not an address? Please give an example of a non-address value you are receiving.

Comment: Hi I cannot share the address name.the issue is I provide locationame to the above code and it returns null in addresslist. but this happens only for few addresses

Comment: If you get null, this usually indicates that the address is malformed - or something in it is incorrect. You need to handle this in your application by flagging it up in your UI as being invalid.

Comment: thanks for your response but it gives me result if i search the same address in google map it just does not work in my code